# Is it safe to use a stainless steel pan after making salt and vinegar brine in it?

Tags: pot, safety

I used my stainless steel pan to dissolve salt in a 30% vinegar/salt solution to kill weeds outside.  After the salt dissolved I let the solution cool.  This stripped the shiny surface of the pan.  The surface still feels smooth like the normal areas.  Is this pan still safe to use for foods?

Comment: aside: don't bother using vinegar as a weed killer, they come back in no time, so you would need to spray every few days to be as effective as a generic roundup knock off.

Answer (score 1):

Your pan is fine, the vinegar and salt just dulled it visually but it is safe to use.